# Image View doesn't match parent's rounded cornered background

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flTodayTraining"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fl_today_training_bg_margin_bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fl_today_training_bg_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/fl_today_training_bg_margin_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/today_training_bg"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvDaysTrained"
                >
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/iv_today_training_detail_height"
                        android:src="@drawable/male_upper_body"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/upper_body"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/tv_today_training_detail_text_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/tv_today_training_detail_padding_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        />
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            </FrameLayout>
```

That's the cornered background of the frame layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners
        android:radius="15dp"
        />

</shape>
```

As you can see in the image, it's rounded in the bottom, but not in the top, how do I make it rounded in all corners?

Please give me an answer that works on all version, not only api 31 +

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Just use `cardView`

see below XML code

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/fruit1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Apple"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and the result is below

[image]

pros-

- you can easily give elevation to `card view` to show shadow
- easily give it radius.
- looks more attractive.
- much more.

I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the background to the FrameLayout set it to the immediate ViewGroup. Also remove fitXy in the imageview

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flTodayTraining"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fl_today_training_bg_margin_bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fl_today_training_bg_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/fl_today_training_bg_margin_horizontal"
                
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvDaysTrained"
                >
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/today_training_bg"<--set it to immediate viewgroup instead
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/iv_today_training_detail_height"
android:foreground="@drawable/some_foreground" <-- insert the new background drawable you created
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/male_upper_body" <-- removed fitXy
                        
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/upper_body"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/tv_today_training_detail_text_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/tv_today_training_detail_padding_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        />
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            </FrameLayout>
```

Create this background drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="8dp"
                    android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/padding_margin_8" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="8dp"
                    android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: This showed the background round, but didn't make the corners of the image round

Comment: Edited my answer please check

Comment: Nope, this made only a border, and no round corners on the image